# TFS Query or SQL Query to Identify Empty Test Plans or Empty Test Suites

Tags: tfs-2015, data-cleaning

We are fairly new to TFS and I have been trying to clean up some of the areas. I can see through a simple TFS query that there are over 180 Test Suites with the name "New suite"... I don't want to try to open each one and look to see if there are test cases assigned to it.

Is there a way to get a report of Empty Test Suites, and maybe Empty Test Plans?

Thanks

Pat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REST API to Get a list of test suites,  "testCaseCount" will be included in the response. See below example:

```
GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/fabrikam-fiber-tfvc/_apis/test/plans/1/suites?api-version=1.0
```

For more information please refer to https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/suites

Besides, you can also get the empty Test Suites or Test Plans by running the sql query in SQL Server, see below sample.

```
  SELECT 
       [SuiteId]
      ,[PlanId]
      ,[ParentSuiteId]
      ,[Title]
      ,[TestCaseCountFromMtm]
      ,[TestCaseCountFromWeb]

  FROM [Tfs_CollectionLC].[dbo].[tbl_Suite]

  WHERE  [TestCaseCountFromMtm]='0' and [TestCaseCountFromWeb]='0'
```

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to get the Plan and Parent Suite name, in above query the "**Title**" column will display all the suite name including the Parent Suite name. I didn't find the exact table to get the Plan name, but we can get it via [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/plans#get-a-list-of-test-plans), you can use below sample PowerShell script to get all the Test Plan names. Just copy/paste the script and save it as .ps1 file to run on your client.

```
$project = "TFVC-Scrum" # Change to your team project name here
$baseUrl = "http://12r2:8080/tfs/CollectionLC"  # Change to your TFS Collection URL         
$testplanUrl = "{0}/{1}/_apis/test/plans?api-version=1.0" -f $baseUrl, $project 
$TestPlans = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $testplanUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential).value

$TestPlanResults = @()

foreach($TestPlan in $TestPlans){
    $testplanitemUrl = "{0}/{1}/_apis/test/plans/{2}?api-version=1.0&includeDetails=true" -f $baseUrl,$project, $TestPlan.id

    $TestPlanItem = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $testplanitemUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "TestPlanid"= $TestPlanItem.id
          "TestPlanName"= $TestPlanItem.name
        } 

    $TestPlanResults += $customObject       
}

$TestPlanResults | Select `
                TestPlanid,
                TestPlanName
```

[image]

Comment: I like the SQL idea, but should I be connecting to the TFS SQL server or the Report Server, and which database shoe I attach to? Sorry for such a basic question...

Pat

Comment: @PatDelaney Yes, you need to connect to the TFS SQL server, just open SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) in your TFS SQL Server machine, then connect to the SQL Server, then  New Query > Copy and Paste above sql query (change to your collection database)  > Execute the query ,you will get the results.

Comment: So I finally got read-only permission form the DBA's. I have cut and pasted the query from above. I also Selected the database I wanted to access from the drop down at the top of the new Query Window. ( I am using SSDT) when I run the query I get:  Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1    Do I have to change TFS_CollectionLC to something else?
Invalid object name 'Tfs_CollectionLC.dbo.tbl_Suite'.

Comment: @PatDelaney Yes, Tfs_CollectionLC is the collection database at my side, you need to change it to your collection database name, So, please check the collection database name in your side, the default collection should be Tfs_DefaultCollection.

Comment: Thanks  That was the missing piece to the puzzle.

Comment: So I now have identified 728 Empty Test Plans or Suites. I want a report to show the managers, but I want to link the PlanID and ParentSuiteID to human names. I'm note sure what query to use to get those from the entire collection.

Comment: @PatDelaney What's that mean for ''human names"? do you want to get the Plan and Parent Suite name? in above query the "Title" column will display all the suite name including the Parent Suite name. I didn't find the exact table to get the Plan name, but we can get it via REST API, Please see the updated answer for details.

Comment: If the Title shows <root> what does that mean? Are those "orphaned" Suites, that perhaps were not deleted properly?

Comment: @PatDelaney Based on my test, each test plan will generate a <root> Title, you can ignore that, just do actions for the non-<root> ones. Please note that we don't recommend do actions directly in TFS DB, If you have to do this, please remember to backup the database first.

Comment: I will probably use witadmin tool to delete the empty suites or the REST api.

Comment: @PatDelaney Yeah,that's secure, please Accept it as an Answer, it the answer resolved your issue. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.